# Converting string values of a list to integer in python: ValueError: invalid literal?

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.5

Example list:

```
mylist=['7', '7_71_E Frastorf', '7', '7_71', '71', 'E Frastorf', '1208', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '40', '40', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '40', '37', '26', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I want to read part of the list elements as integer if the value is not ''.

I have treied:

```
mylist=[int(i)for i in mylist[6:] if i!=" "]
```

But it encounters following error:

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

Could you please help me?
Thanks,
Shiuli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to check for empty strings. This code checks for both space and empty.

```
mylist=['7', '7_71_E Frastorf', '7', '7_71', '71', 'E Frastorf', '1208', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '40', '40', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '40', '37', '26', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''] 

mylist=[int(i) for i in mylist[6:] if i.strip() != '']

print (mylist)
```